# Padrão MVC - A que camada classes de arquivos pertencem?

Tags: php, mvc

A que camada classes destinadas a lidar com arquivos devem ficar? Model ou Controller?

Comment: Eu diria model, mas depende do que vai fazer.

Comment: Se for tipo um handler, acho que seria um Controller.